# Error on PUT request (NetworkError: 415 Unsupported Media Type)

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm trying to send a PUT request using jquery and the server keeps sending "NetworkError: 415 Unsupported Media Type" as a response.

Using the terminal, I can successfully do:

```
curl -X PUT -d '{"data-1" : 2.00, "data-2" : false}' -H "Content-Type:application/json" http://site.com/api/add/none/1053809
```

But the ajax call keeps failing as described:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://site.com/api/add/none/1053809",
    type: "PUT",
    data: '{"data-1" : 2.00, "data-2" : false}',
    success : function(msg) {
        console.log(msg);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the PUT method is not supported on all browsers. Give the latest version of Chrome a go, and see if it works in that.

Comment: I read that from the jQuery source, but I doubt this is the problem. I'm using latest FF.
Also, just tried on latest Chrome and also fails.

Comment: what if you try specifying the contentType or your request as 'application/json'?

Comment: Doing that results in a 400 - Bad Request.